# Unable to Access my text Property in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

    Motor *selectedMotorObject = [[Motor alloc] init];
    selectedMotorObject = (Motor *) [self.motors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.namelabel.text = selectedMotorObject.name;
    detailViewController.chasislbl.text = selectedMotorObject.chasisno;
    detailViewController.policylbl.text = selectedMotorObject.policy;
    detailViewController.makelbl.text = selectedMotorObject.make;
    detailViewController.modelLbl.text = selectedMotorObject.model;
}
```

(`MotorViewController.m`) this is a table view controller

i have created a tableview with customised cell i have certain info details coming on my cell (fname,lname age ) wen i click on the cell and go to the next view i want to see the indivisula details of my cell on my view (where i have put labels n declared outlets for them.. it shows the value on the console but not on the view)

Answer (score 2):

The IBoutlets are initialized only after the view is loaded. So push the view controller (after initializing) first and then set the text values of the labels

Comment: Allocate the viewcontroller as mentioned in my answer. Instead of setting the labels, pass the `Motor` object to the `DetailViewController`. Then, in `viewDidLoad` of `DetailViewController`, set the label texts.

Comment: i have set the label text in detail view controller it show me on the console the value but not updating on the screen im using segue is it sum-thing to do with it??

Comment: What are you logging in the console? selectedMotorObject.name or  detailViewController.namelabel.text?

Comment: selectedMotorObject.name..in detailview controller it give me a null for namelabel.text pls. help stuck on this from two days..

Comment: selectedMotorObject.name this will obviously be logged. This value is not getting set to the label because the label itself is not initialized yet. As Aadhira suggested, pass the Motor obj to the controller.In its viewDidLoad, set the texts of the labels

Comment: Add a property called motor (of type Motor *). Then modify as shown:  
 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

    detailViewController.motor =(Motor *) [self.motors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


-(void)viewDidLoad {
 self.namelabel.text = motor.name;
    self.chasislbl.text = motor.chasisno;
    self.policylbl.text = motor.policy;
    self.makelbl.text = motor.make;
    self.modelLbl.text = motor.model;

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];`,

use

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil];
```

Also, make sure that the labels have required property set.

Comment: first of all thanks.. im using storyboarding.. i have my outlets defined in detailviewcontroller.m n have them connected but wen i run my app and wen i click on my table view cell n navigate to detail view it show me a blank screen can u help??? thanks in advance

Comment: In that case, you don't need to allocate the view controller at all. Pass the `Motor` object through `prepareForSegue:sender`. Then, set the values in `viewDidLoad` of the `DetailViewController`

Comment: im not able to attach a screen shot or u cud have understood better  its like this: in my motorviewcontroller.m i have an array "motors" which is being populated from from another view where i fill in my details.. then wen these details are seen on my table view (i.e. motorviewcontroller) wen i click on accessory indicator it has to go the the next screen n show the details of that particular row.. no i have defined outlets in detailview n connected n synthesized dem.